# Rounded bitmap on progressbar

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a progressbar with the rounded corners in the progression. 
I did nine patch and the progressbar was replicating, how can I solve this problem

XML code

```
<!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#B3FFFFFF"></solid>
        <corners android:radius="15dp"></corners>
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_background_progressbarx"
        android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="left">
    </clip>
</item>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the progressbar was replicating"?

Comment: I'm using a small image of 5x8 (px), which is replicated several times. 
I'm trying to get my image preserve the rounded corners. 

Below is an example of what is happening: 

I have a progressbar 100px for example, if I use an image of 20x10 (px) this image will repeat 5 times. 

I would like to repeat only the middle of the image and preserve the beginning and the end of the image ...

Comment: Are you sure your 9patch image is well done?